# How to dump data spread across multiple tables efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have main table with `worklogs` and some related tables, like `users`, `teams`, etc. I have to provide export functionality that will get up to 100 000 rows and join with 3-4 tables. Currently this task runs in 30-40 seconds which is too much. Any ways to improve performance for this query?

Query itself

```
SELECT "trapping_snaring_trapwork"."id",
       "trapping_snaring_trapwork"."added",
       "trapping_snaring_trapwork"."added_by_id",
       "trapping_snaring_trapwork"."import_id",
       "trapping_snaring_trapwork"."team_id",
       "trapping_snaring_trapwork"."date",
       "contacts_contact"."id",
       "contacts_contact"."added",
       "contacts_contact"."added_by_id",
       "contacts_contact"."team_id",
       "contacts_contact"."first_name",
       "contacts_contact"."last_name",
       "trapping_snaring_trapfeature"."id",
       "trapping_snaring_trapfeature"."added",
       "trapping_snaring_trapfeature"."added_by_id",
       "trapping_snaring_trapfeature"."team_id",
       "trapping_snaring_trapfeature"."name",
       "trapping_snaring_trapfeature"."description",
       "lists_snaringtraptype"."id",
       "lists_snaringtraptype"."added",
       "lists_snaringtraptype"."added_by_id",
       "lists_snaringtraptype"."team_id",
       "lists_snaringtraptype"."name",
       "lists_snaringtraptype"."description",
       "trapping_snaring_groupfeature"."id",
       "trapping_snaring_groupfeature"."added",
       "trapping_snaring_groupfeature"."added_by_id",
       "trapping_snaring_groupfeature"."team_id",
       "trapping_snaring_groupfeature"."name",
       "trapping_snaring_groupfeature"."description",
       "trapping_snaring_groupfeature"."end_date",
       "trapping_session"."id",
       "trapping_session"."added",
FROM "trapping_snaring_trapwork"
INNER JOIN "contacts_contact" ON ("trapping_snaring_trapwork"."checker_id" = "contacts_contact"."id")
INNER JOIN "trapping_snaring_trapfeature" ON ("trapping_snaring_trapwork"."trap_id" = "trapping_snaring_trapfeature"."id")
INNER JOIN "lists_snaringtraptype" ON ("trapping_snaring_trapfeature"."trap_type_id" = "lists_snaringtraptype"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "trapping_snaring_groupfeature" ON ("trapping_snaring_trapfeature"."group_id" = "trapping_snaring_groupfeature"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "trapping_session" ON ("trapping_snaring_trapwork"."session_id" = "trapping_session"."id")

WHERE "trapping_snaring_trapwork"."team_id" = 11;
```

Execution plan:

```
Merge Join  (cost=2358.83..2473.45 rows=11334 width=998) (actual time=22.810..140.677 rows=11336 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: (trapping_snaring_trapwork.checker_id = contacts_contact.id)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.00..12439.20 rows=11334 width=820) (actual time=0.033..103.113 rows=11336 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.86..10436.08 rows=11334 width=513) (actual time=0.029..89.731 rows=11336 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..7170.02 rows=11334 width=401) (actual time=0.024..63.432 rows=11336 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..5033.83 rows=11334 width=231) (actual time=0.020..39.480 rows=11336 loops=1)
                          ->  Index Scan using trapping_snaring_trapwork_checker_id_ae914a8a on trapping_snaring_trapwork  (cost=0.29..796.63 rows=11334 width=74) (actual time=0.012..6.637 rows=11336 loops=1)
                                Filter: (team_id = 11)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                          ->  Index Scan using trapping_snaring_trapfeature_pkey on trapping_snaring_trapfeature  (cost=0.28..0.36 rows=1 width=157) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=11336)
                                Index Cond: (id = trapping_snaring_trapwork.trap_id)
                    ->  Index Scan using lists_snaringtraptype_pkey on lists_snaringtraptype  (cost=0.15..0.18 rows=1 width=170) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=11336)
                          Index Cond: (id = trapping_snaring_trapfeature.trap_type_id)
              ->  Index Scan using trapping_snaring_groupfeature_pkey on trapping_snaring_groupfeature  (cost=0.14..0.28 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=11336)
                    Index Cond: (trapping_snaring_trapfeature.group_id = id)
        ->  Index Scan using trapping_session_pkey on trapping_session  (cost=0.14..0.17 rows=1 width=307) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=11336)
              Index Cond: (trapping_snaring_trapwork.session_id = id)
  ->  Index Scan using contacts_contact_pkey on contacts_contact  (cost=0.29..2257.76 rows=40098 width=178) (actual time=0.006..17.350 rows=50661 loops=1)
Planning time: 19.557 ms
Execution time: 143.044 ms
```

Comment: Your query runs in 143 **milli** seconds (that's 0.1 second). If you are seeing a  runtime of 40 seconds it's your application (or SQL client) that takes that long

Comment: I've tried to execute that query from psql - it takes almost the same time amount - about 40 seconds.

Comment: What size (megabytes) is the return? Could it be taking 40 seconds to return across the network (fetch time) to your client? Your longest step is that `Merge Join` and it's running in `140.677ms`. This query is executing lightning fast, so the times you are seeing don't appear to be coming from your database.